# ExtJS-4: override on method 'onMouseDown' ain't working

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I m not able to override the function 'onmousedown' from the class 
Ext.util.Floating.
the sample is given below.
Is there some pattern to follow if i want to override functions with 'on' prefix?
constructor is getting invoked form the overridden code block but 'onMouseDown' still reverts back to the ext-all-debug file.

```
Ext.define('Ext.util.Floating.override', {
    override: 'Ext.util.Floating',
    constructor: function(){console.log('onmousedown: This gets invoked.')},
    onMouseDown: function (e) {
        console.log('OverrideOnMouseDown');
        var focusTask = this.focusTask;

        if (this.floating && (!focusTask || !focusTask.id)) {
            this.toFront(!!e.getTarget(':focusable'));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please try to include a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jnk) and I will work on it.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of the class 'Ext.util.Floating' was hardcoded to pick up the method 'onMouseDown' with out checking for any override.

I overrode the constructor as well and implemented the check of override on 'onMouseDown' existence.

```
Ext.define('Ext.util.Floating.override', {
    override: 'Ext.util.Floating',
    constructor: function(){
        .
        .
        .
        me.mon(me.el, {
                //redirects to the overridden method we provided.
                mousedown: me.mixins.floating.onMouseDown ? me.mixins.floating.onMouseDown: me.onMouseDown,
                scope: me
        });
        .
        .
        .
    },
    onMouseDown: function (e) {
        console.log('OverrideOnMouseDown');
        var focusTask = this.focusTask;

        if (this.floating && (!focusTask || !focusTask.id)) {
            this.toFront(!!e.getTarget(':focusable'));
        }
    } 
});
```